# Is display:none automatically means that iframe and it's content not exists?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, methods

I have an `iframe`. Inside of it I only run a javascript which update some value and handle a `POST` method (for prevent reload the whole page). My question is if I set it to `display:none;` will the script and the `POST` method work? Or should I set it to some kind of negative position?

What is the best solution (I know maybe AJAX request but it's a bit complex to develop in my case)

Comment: It still exists...look in live html in browser dev tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`display: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)** does **not** remove the element from the DOM, but rather the DOM **flow**.

Note that this is different to **[`visibility: hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility)**, which simply *hides* the element, while leaving it in place in the DOM. If the element occupies space, the space will still remain occupied, leaving a gap.

It is impossible for CSS to actually alter the DOM, and neither rule will prevent embedded `<script>` tags from executing:

```css
.one {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"><script>alert('hi');</script></div>
```